# How can i get an object with checks on nested object in Spring boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I am unable to to get what i intend using a JpaRepository. I'll try to explain what I want using the following code:

Repository

```
 @Repository
public interface CompanyRepository extends JpaRepository<Company, Long> {

    Optional<Company> findByIdAndBranches_parent_idIsNull(Long id);
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class BillService {

@Autowired
private CompanyRepository companyRepository;

@Autowired
private BranchRepository branchRepository;

public Company getCompanyById(Long id)
{
    Optional<Company> company = companyRepository.findByIdAndBranches_parent_idIsNull(id);
    return company.get();
}
```

Company Entity class

```
public class Company 
{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String name;

private String address;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
private List<Branch> branches;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
private List<User> users;
```

}

Branch Entity class

```
@Entity
public class Branch 
{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String name;

private String address;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
private Company company;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private Branch parent;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private List<Branch> subBranches;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "branch")
private List<User> users;

}
```

Now what i want to get is company with branches having parent id NULL but am getting all branches irrespective of parent id

This is what i want as result

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Lakshya",
"address": "Bahadurgarh",
"branches": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Lakshya Branch1",
        "address": "Bahadurgarh1",
        "subBranches": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Lakshya Branch1_3",
                "address": "Bahadurgarh1_3",
                "subBranches": [],
                "users": []
            }
        ],
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "User3_Company1_Branch1",
                "address": "Bgz"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"users": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "User_Company1",
        "address": "Bgz"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "User_Company1_Branch1",
        "address": "Bgz"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "User3_Company1_Branch1",
        "address": "Bgz"
    }
]
}
```

But this is what am getting

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Lakshya",
"address": "Bahadurgarh",
"branches": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Lakshya Branch1",
        "address": "Bahadurgarh1",
        "subBranches": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Lakshya Branch1_3",
                "address": "Bahadurgarh1_3",
                "subBranches": [],
                "users": []
            }
        ],
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "User3_Company1_Branch1",
                "address": "Bgz"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Lakshya Branch1_3",
        "address": "Bahadurgarh1_3",
        "subBranches": [],
        "users": []
    }
],
"users": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "User_Company1",
        "address": "Bgz"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "User_Company1_Branch1",
        "address": "Bgz"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "User3_Company1_Branch1",
        "address": "Bgz"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: This is being asked again and again. If you only want specific branches, your query needs to **select** branches. You query selects companies. So you get companies. And when asking for a company's branches, you get the company's branches, because COmpanybranches will always contain all the company's branches: that's the contract of the method.

Comment: Let's say you have 2 brothers named "John" and "Paul". Your query is equivalent to asking "who has a brother named "John". So I get you, Lakshya, as an answer. **Then** I ask you "who are your brothers". That's the equivalent of calling company.getBranches(). And obviously, the answer is "John" and "Paul". If I only want the brothers named "John", then I should ask "who is the brother of Lakshya and is named "John". Then I'll only get your brother John.

Comment: @JBNizet So how to do it? I am beginner in spring and i was not getting anything else out of any tutorial for this. Can you guide me ?

Comment: That has nothing to do with Spring. The technology you're using to get data out of your database is named JPA, and its implementation is Hibernate. That's where you should look for documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to filter out associated entities, you can use [@Where](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-where). It's not a part of JPA specification, but JPA implementation by Hibernate provides this annotation.  So you can specify any additional conditions:

```
public class Company 
{
    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    @Where(clause = "parent_id is null")
    private List<Branch> branches;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    private List<User> users;
}
```

Then you have to change the repository's method name, since you don't need extra condition anymore:

```
@Repository
public interface CompanyRepository extends JpaRepository<Company, Long> {
    Optional<Company> findById(Long id);
}
```

Using this approach you always get companies with only branches that don't have parent. If you need to get all branches of a company (whether they have parent or not) you can create and use repository for `Branch` entity class.